# How to implement if-else using n for n in m iteration

Tags: python

I iterate a list of dictionaries:

```
dictList=[{1:'One'}, {2:'Two'), {1:'One',7:'Seven'}]
result=[eachDict.get(1) for eachDict in dictList if eachDict.get(1)]
```

checking if dictionary key `1` is presented. If `1` key is not in a dictionary I want it to return key `7` (instead of `1` key).
Once again, if there is key `1` return it. If there is no `1` key try to return `7` key. How to achieve this?

Comment: You will have to provide _several_ examples to clarify things. At least to me...

Comment: what happens if there are no 7's or 1's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I think this is easier to do in a loop. No reason to always try to mash everything into a list comprehension. Sometimes a for loop is easier to write, read, understand, and extend.

```
dictlist = [{1: 'One'}, {2: 'Two'}, {1: 'One', 7: 'Seven'}]

result = []
for d in dictlist:
    if 1 in d:
        result.append(d[1])
    elif 7 in d:
        result.append(d[7])
    # else:
    #     Possibly do something here?
```

---

If efficiency is important, some timing

```
def my_func():
    result = []
    for d in dictlist:
        if 1 in d:
            result.append(d[1])
        elif 7 in d:
            result.append(d[7])
        else:
            result.append(None)  # To match their implementations

%timeit my_func()  # My answer
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 646 ns per loop

%timeit [d.get(1) if 1 in d else d.get(7) for d in dictList]  # Hamatti's answer
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 808 ns per loop

%timeit [d.get(1, d.get(7)) for d in dictList]  # Peter DeGlopper's answer
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 us per loop
```

Though keep in mind that these timings are done on the `d` provided. I have no idea how all of these scale up to larger dictionaries, or what kind of scale you're working on. If it isn't *extremely* larger, then efficiency won't matter at all.

Comment: @Sputnix It's actually probably not slower than a list comprehension. In general, list comprehensions are about the same speed as for loops,

Comment: From what I tested list comprehension is up to 30% faster

Comment: @Sputnix, you are getting None values added in your list comp though

Comment: Thanks for a test. It looks like list comprehensive is only fast when you keep it short!

Comment: What do you want to happen for dicts that lack both keys, if "None is not cool"? Just nothing added to the list, so that the example in Hamatti's answer should be `['One', 'Seven']`? I think that'd end up being less readable if done in a comprehension than in a for loop.

Comment: Looks like this time I go with all old school for loop instead of list comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

You can do as follows

```
>> dictList=[{1:'One'}, {2:'Two'}, {7:'Seven'}]
>> [d.get(1) if 1 in d else d.get(7) for d in dictList]
['One', None, 'Seven']
```

Answer (score 3):

Roger Fan's answer is good, but here's an alternate using nested `get`s in case you really want to be concise:

```
result = [d.get(1, d.get(7)) for d in dictList]
```

This looks up both values, because Python always evaluates all its function call's arguments - `get` does not shortcircuit. So it's marginally less efficient than an iterative approach. I think Hamatti's answer is equivalent, doing two key lookups each time (one to check `in`, one to `get` whichever is chosen), but none of these will have performance problems.

One way to satisfy the requirement that `None` not be added for dicts that lack both keys is this ugliness:

```
result = [x for x in (d.get(1, d.get(7)) for d in dictList) if x]
```

That uses an internal generator object, so it doesn't traverse twice. But at that point I would definitely use a `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

For just a couple of elements to look for, stick with the other solutions, but if you have more keys, a long list of *if/elif/else* is not nice, so you could create a custom getter that returns the first available element:

```
def firstgetter(*items):
    def getter(dic):
        for item in items:
            if item in dic:
                return dic[item]
    return getter
```

### Example

```
dictList=[{1: 'One'}, {2: 'Two'}, {2: 'Two', 7: 'Seven'}]
map(firstgetter(1, 7), dictList)  # ['One', None, 'Seven']
```